# How do I improve audio quality when calling with 3rd party apps? (e.g. Messenger, Discord, Zoom, etc.)

Tags: audio, zooming, compression

When I use apps like Discord, Facebook Messenger, Zoom, and Google Meets to call people, it compresses the audio like it would in a normal phone call, even though using those same apps from the desktop give much better audio.

How do I go about making this audio sound better and not so compressed?

I'm using a Pixel 3 XL and am on AT&T (although most of the calls happen over Wi-Fi so I don't see how that matters).

Answer (score -1):

Facebook messenger, Google Duo and other messaging app call use internet connection. Many internet service provider restrict bandwidth for such call. Using 5G network can improve your call quality.

You can use Lease line for internet connection. Such connection does not have any speed limit. You need Lease line on both side then you can get good call quality.

Also update your app to latest version.

Comment: OP says they have no issues on Desktop, so ISP can't be the issue, unless by ISP you meant telecom service provider (which also provides internet to their users). 4G is not a weak technology for internet calling, so I don't see why you would recommend 5G as a magical solution that would solve the issue over 4G.

Comment: Anyone has any solution other than what I said. If Yes than provide solution. At&t has 4G LTE and he is not getting quality.

Comment: I'm using my phone over the same wifi that I'm using on desktop. The cell provider has little to do with my internet connection in this scenario